Parameterization of the intersection between a cone and a paraboloid
I'm solving some exercises on arc length of intersection of surfaces and I cannot conclude the following:

Calculate the arc length of the curve give by the intersection of the surfaces $z^2 = 2x^2 + 2y^2$ and $z = 4-x^2-y^2$.

My problem is to find a parameterization of this curve. I tried to get some simple expression but I could not. The simpler expression I got, equaling the surfaces, was
$$(x' + y')^2 - 10(x' + y') = -16$$
where $x' = x^2$, $y' = y^2$. I suspect that this is not the right way to do this.

Notice (by sketching the surfaces) that the intersection must be the union of two circles, so all that is needed is to determine their radii. Let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then from the cone equation we deduce $z^2=2r^2$ and from the paraboloid we deduce $z=4-r^2$. Plugging the second equation into the first yields a quadratic in $r^2$:
$$(4-r^2)^2 = 2r^2 \implies r^4 - 10r^2 + 16=0\implies r^2 = 2,8$$
You can of course find their heights and then parametrize the circles, but you can also calculate the circumference directly to see that the arc length of the two curves is $2\pi(\sqrt2+\sqrt8)$.
